# Dyanmic Where Clause

Tags: t-sql

Is there a way to make your comparison operator dynamic?

EG:

```
SELECT
    *

FROM TABLE

WHERE
    IIF(@FLAG_A = 'True', COLUMN_A = @COLUMN_A, COLUMN_A <> @COLUMN_A)
AND IIF(@FLAG_B = 'True', COLUMN_B = @COLUMN_B, COLUMN_B <> @COLUMN_B)
AND IIF(@FLAG_C = 'True', COLUMN_C = @COLUMN_C, COLUMN_C <> @COLUMN_C)
```

I tried the above example with my parameters set as @FLAG_A = 'True', @FLAG_B = 'False' @FLAG_C = 'False'

I was expecting this query to run:

```
SELECT
    *

FROM TABLE

WHERE
    COLUMN_A = @COLUMN_A
AND COLUMN_B <> @COLUMN_B
AND COLUMN_C <> @COLUMN_C
```

But I'm getting:
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood [IIF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) - as per the documentation, `IIF` returns one of two scalar values; you cannot use an inline function to modify a query predicate, you should use `and` and `or` logic

Comment: What you wrote would have worked in a more consistent world. SQL Server supports a [boolean](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#boolean-data-type) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a **Boolean** data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set."  `IIF` can only cope with a `boolean` first argument, not the second and/or third, and cannot return a `boolean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use explicit `AND` and `OR` logic. Also adding `RECOMPILE` to the `OPTION` clause is going to be a likely benefit, as the plans could be *very* different for each set of variables.

Unfortunately, due to your logic, this does look someone messy:

```sql
SELECT {Column List} --Don't use SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ((@FLAG_A = 'true' AND COLUMN_A = @COLUMN_A) OR (@FLAG_A <> 'true' AND COLUMN_A <> @COLUMN_A))
  AND ((@FLAG_B = 'true' AND COLUMN_B = @COLUMN_B) OR (@FLAG_B <> 'true' AND COLUMN_B <> @COLUMN_B))
  AND ((@FLAG_C = 'true' AND COLUMN_C = @COLUMN_C) OR (@FLAG_C <> 'true' AND COLUMN_C <> @COLUMN_C))
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

The alternative approach would be to create a parametrised dynamic statement. This may perform better (and allows for caching of plans), however, does require a *better* level of understanding:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT {Column List}' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.YourTable' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE ' + IIF(@FLAG_A = 'True',N' COLUMN_A = @COLUMN_A', N'COLUMN_A <> @COLUMN_A') + @CRLF +
           N'  AND ' + IIF(@FLAG_B = 'True',N' COLUMN_B = @COLUMN_B', N'COLUMN_B <> @COLUMN_B') + @CRLF +
           N'  AND ' + IIF(@FLAG_C = 'True',N' COLUMN_C = @COLUMN_C', N'COLUMN_C <> @COLUMN_C') + N';';

--Note the data type are guessed, and you will need to correct these.
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@COLUMN_A varchar(20), @COLUMN_B varchar(20), @COLUMN_C varchar(20)', @COLUMN_A, @COLUMN_B, @COLUMN_C;
```

Comment: I tried your second method, but I had an additional question. How do I pass values to those parameters on the EXEC string? I'm getting:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: That's already demonstrated in the above, @JunH . The parameters are defined in the second parameter for `sys.sp_executesql` and then they are passed in the 3rd parameter onwards.

Comment: Prior to the SP call I can supply the "real" values of the parameters? I just don't understand why that line is complaining about a ')'. If I run everything without calling the SP to run the SQL it runs without issue.

Comment: That doesn't look anything like the query I've got above, I'm afraid, @JunH .  Is there a reason you're (ab)using the `NOLOCK` hint there? Do you need to use it? If so, why are you not changing the isolation level instead? `STRING_SPLIT(@Column_C + ,',')` isn't valid syntax though; you can't concatenate to nothing.

Comment: In truth, @JunH , it looks like you have a new question, so I would suggest [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thank you for your resposnes. The @Column_C is a variable, it wouldn't be empty. Trying to figure out where to supply the value. I'll keep working on it. Thank you.

Comment: The value of `@ColumnC` is passed to the dynamic statement as the 5th variable in the able, @JunH . The point in my last comment is about `STRING_SPLIT(@Column_C + ,',')`; notice you have `@Column_C +` but you don't have anything after the concatenation operator (`+`); that is your syntax error. The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` the statement first. Then you can debug that SQL and solve the problem before propagating the solution to your SQL that generates the dynamic statement.

Comment: How did I miss that "+"! That did it! Thank you.